# Platform to save iOS app images online

Tags: ios

I have an iOS app that has over 100 images pre-stored in it. I want to have a system where all the images are saved online and picked by the app. Other then maintaining an own server, what other online options are available to save and retrieve such amount of data. And what are options available to save high scores of the iOS application online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse could be made to work to save and access the images.

Game Center is great for high scores and Crystal, Geosophic, and Plus+ are all alternatives as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can integrate apple's iCloud in your app to store any data.

this is the link-https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/Introduction.html

for store high scores you may use game centre.